# MongoError: topology was destroyed, how can i fix it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, server, topology

i am using mongo server and on node.js

when  trying to use my function to find client by name for the second time i get ther error of "topology was destroyed"

```
function findClient(Fname,res){
    let query = {name:Fname}
    dbo.collection("clients").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result.name);
        res.send(result)
        db.close();
    });
}
```

Comment: Restart might fix your problem

Comment: as my experience thought me, is that the node process / server terminated before the query had time to return..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Firewall is not blocking your requests, might has something to do with your VPN/Proxy if you're in a company's local network.

[Similar issue where the problem was related to Firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41227124/mongo-throwing-topology-was-destroyed-after-one-connection)

Also you might need to ensure the use and location of db.close()

[Same issue where the problem was an 'errant close() call' causing the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331966/what-could-cause-a-topology-was-destroyed-error-when-calling-db-destroydatabas)